# How to make a clickable transition bar graph to show 3 graphs in d3 v4?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Is there a way to make a clickable transition bar graph so that there are 3 different graphs involved? So that it automatically loads graph 1, and then when you click it shows graph 2, and then when you click again it shows graph 3, and finally if you click again it goes back to graph 1?

Current Code

```
var w = 600;
 var h = 250;

 var dataset = [5, 10, 13, 19, 21, 25, 22, 18, 15, 13,
   11, 12, 15, 20, 18, 17, 16, 18, 23, 25
 ];

 var xScale = d3.scaleBand()
   .domain(d3.range(dataset.length))
   .rangeRound([0, w])
   .padding(0.1);

 var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
   .domain([0, d3.max(dataset)])
   .range([0, h]);

 //Create SVG element
 var svg = d3.select("body")
   .append("svg")
   .attr("width", w)
   .attr("height", h);
 //Create bars
 svg.selectAll("rect")
   .data(dataset)
   .enter()
   .append("rect")
   .attr("x", function(d, i) {
     return xScale(i);
   })
   .attr("y", function(d) {
     return h - yScale(d);
   })
   .attr("width", xScale.bandwidth())
   .attr("height", function(d) {
     return yScale(d);
   })
   .attr("fill", function(d) {
     return "rgb(0, 0, " + (d * 10) + ")";
   });
 //Create labels
 svg.selectAll("text")
   .data(dataset)
   .enter()
   .append("text")
   .text(function(d) {
     return d;
   })
   .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
   .attr("x", function(d, i) {
     return xScale(i) + xScale.bandwidth() / 2;
   })
   .attr("y", function(d) {
     return h - yScale(d) + 14;
   })
   .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
   .attr("font-size", "11px")
   .attr("fill", "white");
 //On click, update with new data            
 d3.select("p")
   .on("click", function() {
     //New values for dataset
     dataset = [11, 12, 15, 20, 18, 17, 16, 18, 23, 25,
       5, 10, 13, 19, 21, 25, 22, 18, 15, 13
     ];
     //Update all rects
     svg.selectAll("rect")
       .data(dataset)
       .transition() // <-- This makes it a smooth transition!
       .attr("y", function(d) {
         return h - yScale(d);
       })
       .attr("height", function(d) {
         return yScale(d);
       })
       .attr("fill", function(d) {
         return "rgb(0, 0, " + (d * 10) + ")";
       });
     //Update all labels
     svg.selectAll("text")
       .data(dataset)
       .text(function(d) {
         return d;
       })
       .attr("y", function(d) {
         return h - yScale(d) + 14;
       });

   });

<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<p>Click on this text to update the chart with new data values (once).</p>
```

Comment: Please check with this https://jsfiddle.net/rcwzbja5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a function which returns data like this:

```
function getMyData(){
   count++;//here count is a global counter.
   if(count%3 == 0){
     return [11, 12, 15, 20, 18, 17, 16, 18, 23, 25,
       5, 10, 13, 19, 21, 25, 22, 18, 15, 13
     ];
   } else if(count%3 == 1){
      return[5, 10, 13, 19, 21, 25, 22, 18, 15, 13,
       11, 12, 15, 20, 18, 17, 16, 18, 23, 25
     ];
   } else if(count%3 == 2){
      return [15, 10, 3, 19, 21, 15, 12, 8, 25, 23,
       21, 22, 5, 20, 18, 7, 6, 18, 13, 15
     ];
   }
 }
```

Now call the `getMyData` function on click, for each dataset the bars will get updated.

working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/1PGrsXchSQl4krOk0poM?p=preview)